# Google Oauth not working after uploading to alpha testing

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play, google-oauth-java-client

I'm using google sign-in in my app

It's working fine when debugging but the login don't work after uploaded signed-apk for alpha testing on google play store.

The error is

> status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}

I got the sha-1 for release config and added it to firebase but the problem is the same

Finally I tried installing the apk without uploading to google play, it worked but after uploading the same apk the application downloaded from google play shows the same error

I'm using android studio 2.3.3 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I'm generating sha-1 using gradle->tasks->android->signingReport

build config for release are:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file('filePlace')
        storePassword "pass"
        keyAlias "alias"
        keyPassword "pass"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When uploading the app as alpha testing, google makes some changes on your apk.

I added the sha-1 found in app signing tab in my google play console to the firebase app then every thing is okay.